# How to alias or rename a file on the fly in Linux?

Tags: linux, file, rename, alias, on-the-fly

I have the following challenge under Linux:

- An application is writing a config-file "samename.cfg" into certain directories
- I want to have the config-file named different for each directory
- I do not want any file called "samename.cfg" written to the directories
- I can not change it in the application

So I would like to have the application thinking that it accesses `samename.cfg` but in fact it reads and writes `anothername.cfg`. Symlink does not help, because then there still is a file called `samename.cfg` in every directory.

Anybody any idea?

Regards,
Axel

Comment: Consider using some [file system in user space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try using a hard link instead of a soft link when using `ln` command (just remove the `-s` flag).

See [ln man's page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ln.1.html) for more details.